# White space in awk print and match

Tags: regex, awk, tmux

I have an awk statement to print my battery indicator on tmux I found in a gist:

`set -g status-right "batt: #(pmset -g batt | awk 'NR==2 {gsub(/;/,\"\"\\); \                                                                                               print (match($3,/^ch/\\) ? \"\ \":\"\"\\) $2 $4}') | %d-%h %H:%M "`

This ends up printing: `batt: 60%2:18 | 05-Aug 11:51`

How can I insert a space after the 60% and 2:18? The $2 variable is is the 60% and the $4 is the 2:18.

So I'd like it to output:
`batt: 60% 2:18 | 05-Aug 11:51`

I tried adding space at every possible point but it is not changing. Is there a specific way to add whitespace in awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
awk 'NR==2 {gsub(/;/,\"\"\\);print (match($3,/^ch/\\) ? \"\ \":\"\"\\),$2,$4}'
```

You need to use a comma to separate the output with the `OFS` *(output field separator)* in `awk` which by default is a single space. Without the comma you're doing string concatenation.